# Dropdown no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy migrando un sistema y el dropdown dejó de funcionar, mi código es el siguiente, alguien se le ocurre que puede ser?

```
<span class="action-button muted" data-dropdown="#sort-dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $sort_options[$sort_cols]; ?>">
<i class="icon-caret-down pull-right"></i>
<span><i class="icon-sort-by-attributes-alt <?php if ($sort_dir) echo 'icon-flip-vertical'; ?>"></i> <?php echo __('Sort');?></span>
</span>
<div id="sort-dropdown" class="action-dropdown anchor-right"
onclick="javascript:
var query = addSearchParam({'sort': $(event.target).data('mode'), 'dir': $(event.target).data('dir')});
$.pjax({
    url: '?' + query,
    timeout: 2000,
    container: '#pjax-container'});">
  <ul class="bleed-left">
    <?php foreach ($queue_sort_options as $mode) {
    $desc = $sort_options[$mode];
    $icon = '';
    $dir = '0';
    $selected = $sort_cols == $mode; ?>
    <li <?php
    if ($selected) {
    echo 'class="active"';
    $dir = ($sort_dir == '1') ? '0' : '1'; // Flip the direction
    $icon = ($sort_dir == '1') ? 'icon-hand-up' : 'icon-hand-down';
    }
    ?>>
        <a href="#" data-mode="<?php echo $mode; ?>" data-dir="<?php echo $dir; ?>">
          <i class="icon-fixed-width <?php echo $icon; ?>"
          ></i> <?php echo Format::htmlchars($desc); ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php } ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Tal vez pueda llegar a ser por la versión de Jquery aunque sinceramente eso me da igual, solamente quiero solucionar el problema

**Este sería mi header**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/filedrop.field.js?9ae093d"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/redactor.min.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/redactor-plugins.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/redactor-osticket.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/select2.min.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/fabric.min.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?9ae093d"></script>

<script src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>js/osticket.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>scp/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js?9ae093d"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Donde pone `$.pjax({` no debe ser `$.ajax({`?

Comment: Falta mucha información en la pregunta. ¿Que tipo de migración estas haciendo? ¿Que es lo que has cambiado y lo cual ha hecho que deje de funcionar los dropdown? Para preguntas de este tipo es conveniente aportar un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Aparte de el detalle que hay con el `$.pjax({` que ya lo comento "Evgeni Enchev", Creo que deberías revisar la consola del navegador a ver que te reporta. Eso da muchas pistas de que es lo que esta causando el problema. Si usas Chrome, usa Ctrl+Mayús+I y luego le das a la pestaña de consola, seguro te aparecerán las alertas correspondientes. Avísanos como te va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero revisa que tengas cargado la librería para `pjax` [revisa aqui en github jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)  , ahora veo que estas usando boostrap 4.1.0 para el dropdown,este version requiere `popper.js` y `Jquery > 3`

```html
<head>
<!-- style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    EL MENU
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" onclick="javascript:console.log( $(event.target).data('mode'))">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-mode="mode1" data-dir="/home">Menu 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item " href="#" data-mode="mode2" data-dir="/foo">Menu 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-mode="mode3" data-dir="/bar">Menu 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Dale [Ejecutar] espero te funcione. ( no agregue el código php porque bueno estoy en stackoverflow xD ) espero te sirve si tiene alguno duda deja comentario.